# What heating element can I use to make a coffee robot?

Tags: cooling

I'm seeking a <=10 AMP wall-outlet heating element that can rapidly heat 300-1200 grams of water to 205 degree Fahrenheit, attached to the side of a glass container.

I just purchased [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BDB4UG), but it's bigger than I thought it was going to be.
[image]

There are two other similar, but smaller ones on Amazon that will not work because they are too short - they're less than 3 inches or so.  The device should work for varied water levels: something like 2-6 inches or so.  Most of this type of element will burn up if used without being submerged.

Comment: I've closed this question as off-topic because it's [not within our scope definition](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/265/what-is-hardware). Much as I like the question, it's not currently on-topic.